# How to Display My Own Custom Fields on Wordpress Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I treid to create loop for display Custom Fields on single page of post

```
        <?php 
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

        foreach($meta as $key=>$val)
        {
            echo '<li><span>' . $key . ' : </span>' . $val[0] . '</li>';
        }
        ?>
```

But this code displays All of Custom Fields of post,

Is there a way to just display my own added Custom Fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All post_meta fields are saved into the Database with the same structure. If you need to loop a specific subset of meta, you can give them a similar name structure so you can filter them.

For example, if you give all your custom meta a name starting with 'my_custom_meta_' the code would be:

```
<?php 
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

    foreach($meta as $key=>$val) {
        if(preg_match('/^my_custom_meta_.+/', $key)) { 
              echo '<li><span>' . $key . ' : </span>' . $val[0] . '</li>';
        }
    }

 ?>
```